# Calling Invoke hangs program

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke, begininvoke

Basically, this is what happens. I have a thread(endless loop) that runs as a background process while the form is showing. The thread checks if there is a need to add a new ToolStripMenuItem.

If the conditions are met, I'll need to use Invoke in order to create the UI object right? Problem with this is, when the this.Invoke or BeginInvoke is called, the form became unresponsive while the thread that does the checking is still running fine. Any ideas?

This is the first time i'm trying with this multithreading thingee. I'm sure i've missed out something.

```
 public void ThreadSetCom()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string[] tmpStrPort = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            IEnumerable<string> diff = tmpStrPort.Except(strPort);
            strPort = tmpStrPort;
            System.Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames().Length);
            foreach (string p in diff)
            {
                var cpDropdown = (ToolStripMenuItem)msMenu.Items["connectToolStripMenuItem"];
                cpDropdown = (ToolStripMenuItem)cpDropdown.DropDownItems["connectReaderToolStripMenuItem"];

                ToolStripMenuItem tsmi = new ToolStripMenuItem();
                tsmi.Text = p;
                tsmi.Name = p;
                tsmi.Click += new EventHandler(itm_Click);

                if (this.msMenu.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    GUIUpdate d = new GUIUpdate(ThreadSetCom);
                    this.Invoke(d);
                }
                else
                {
                    cpDropdownList.DropDownItems.Add(tsmi);
                }                
            }                
        }
    }
```

Comment: We'll need more detail - ideally a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. What exactly does the code you're invoking look like?

Comment: Hi Jon, I'm trying to invoke the method ThreadSetCom which is the one above. The delegate GUIUpdate will just call back the same method it is in. I'm not sure if this is the right way to update the UI. I've seen few samples that does this so I'm just trying out.

In short, this method is being called in the form constructor. And thats it. Nothing much. But its not working. Anything wrong that you noticed?

Comment: Please show how you're starting the child thread. Are you calling `Join` on it somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ThreadSetCom` method never exits:

```
while (true)
```

... with no `return` or `break` statements. That's going to hang the UI thread forever.

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but you definitely don't want to be looping like that in the UI thread. I'd argue that you don't want to be looping like that in a *tight* way in any thread, mind you...

Comment: Hi Jon... thanks for pointing out the obvious mistake. I feel so silly. But actually i thought the invoke statement would somehow(magically) make it to work. This is my first time using it, so i have this weird expectation. And the samples that i've seen so far put the code in this way, so i thought its the way to do it. But thanks for your help though :)

Comment: @user1885498: I doubt that many of them have included an infinite loop :) Additionally, you're already accessing the UI within that loop... which you shouldn't be doing unless you're already within the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach for you would probably be to use a `BackgroundWorker`. I say that because what you're experiencing isn't that uncommon when doing multi-threading in a Windows Forms application. Further, the `BackgroundWorker` is able to manage the thread switching properly. Let me give you an example of that code with the `BackgroundWorker`.

### Build a private class variable

```
private BackgroundWorker _worker;
```

### Add to the CTOR

```
public {ctor}()
{
    _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    _worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

    _worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(BackgroundThreadWork);
    _worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(BackgroundThreadProgress);
}
```

### DoWork handler

```
private void BackgroundThreadWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (!_worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        string[] tmpStrPort = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        IEnumerable<string> diff = tmpStrPort.Except(strPort);
        strPort = tmpStrPort;
        System.Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames().Length);
        foreach (string p in diff)
        {
            _worker.ReportProgress(1, p);
        }                
    }
}
```

### Report progress handler

```
private void BackgroundThreadProgress(object sender, ReportProgressEventArgs e)
{
    var cpDropdown = (ToolStripMenuItem)msMenu.Items["connectToolStripMenuItem"];
    cpDropdown = (ToolStripMenuItem)cpDropdown.DropDownItems["connectReaderToolStripMenuItem"];

    ToolStripMenuItem tsmi = new ToolStripMenuItem();
    tsmi.Text = e.UserState as string;
    tsmi.Name = e.UserState as string;
    tsmi.Click += new EventHandler(itm_Click);

    cpDropdownList.DropDownItems.Add(tsmi);
}
```

## The Loop

However, one thing you're going to have to do is figure out how to get out of this loop. When should it exit? Whatever that means, you need to ***add*** to the *if* statement that exists there in my example because this loop will never end otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

What the effect of this code snippet:

```
GUIUpdate d = new GUIUpdate(ThreadSetCom);
this.Invoke(d);
```

is that the method 'ThreadSetCom' will be invoked in the UI thread. And there is an infinitive loop in that method. That is why your form becomes unresponsive.

I suggest you that you should move the `foreach` clause to a separate method and invoke this method in the UI thread when the condition is hit, for example the diff.Count>0.